# Error in Caching a Table in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to cache a Table available in Hive(using `spark-shell`). Given below is my code

```
scala> val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

scala> hiveContext.cacheTable("sparkdb.firsttable")
```

and I am getting the below Exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientInterface$$anonfun$getTable$1.apply(ClientInterface.scala:112)
```

The table `firsttable` is available in database `sparkdb`(in Hive). Looks like the issue seems to be in providing database name. How do I achieve this?

PS : HiveQL query like the one shown below does work without any issues

`scala> hiveContext.sql("select * from sparkdb.firsttable")`

Find below results from few other method calls

```
scala> hiveContext.tables("sparkdb")
res14: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [tableName: string, isTemporary: boolean]

scala> hiveContext.tables("sparkdb.firsttable")
res15: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [tableName: string, isTemporary: boolean]
```

Comment: What happens when you call `hiveContext.table("sparkdb.firsttable")`? Or even `hiveContext.tables("sparkdb")`?

Comment: @JustinPihony, I get the Exception shown above 'NoSuchTableException'

Comment: Is it listed in my second query?

Comment: @JustinPihony, when I use `hiveContext.table("sparkdb")`, I get the same exception `NoSuchTableException`

Comment: Ok, what about hiveContext.tables()?

Comment: @JustinPihony, sorry, `hiveContex.tables("sparkdb")` & `hiveContext.tables("sparkdb.firsttable")` does work. Have updated my question with the results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83593/discussion-between-justin-pihony-and-raj).

Comment: After looking into this, I think this is a bug. The sql analyzer parses the dots, but the sqlcontext does not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I was right, this seems to be [SPARK-8105](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8105). So, for now, your best bet is to do the `select *` and cache that.