# StackOverflowError when Caching a Table in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've been trying to cache a table created from a 30 MB csv file in SparkSQL and I get a StackOverflowError. Here's my code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CorrelationApp").setMaster("local[2]")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val sqlContext=new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true") //  Use first line of all files as header
  .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types, needs databricks csv 1.4 or above
  //columns named "Row0","Row1", etc
  .load("rngData.csv")

df.registerTempTable("dataset")
sqlContext.cacheTable("dataset")
val cols = df.columns //array of column ids 

//Dummy value -- can be anything
val thing = "Row1"

//Find correlations and find the top 10
val test = cols.map{colId => 
    println(s"On thing: ${colId}")
    //get a two-column dataframe with no nulls
    val results = sqlContext.sql(s"SELECT ${thing}, ${colId} FROM dataset WHERE (${colId} IS NOT NULL AND ${thing} IS NOT NULL)")
    //correlate the two columns
    (results.stat.corr(colId, thing) , colId)
  }.sortWith(_._1 > _._1)
  //(take 11 because the #1 is always going to be the column itself)
  val ans = test.take(11)
  ans.foreach{f => println(s"${f._1}, ${f._2}")}
```

Here's the output:

```
[Stage 1:>                                                          (0 + 2) / 2]
                                                                                On thing: Row0


[Stage 2:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 2]
[Stage 2:>                                                          (0 + 2) / 2]


[Stage 2:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 2]
[Stage 2:>                                                          (0 + 2) / 2]
[Stage 2:=============================>                             (1 + 1) / 2]
                                                                                On thing: Row1


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference.equals(namedExpressions.scala:196)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.contains(Set.scala:64)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.$plus(Set.scala:66)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.$plus(Set.scala:61)
    at scala.collection.mutable.SetBuilder.$plus$eq(SetBuilder.scala:24)
    at scala.collection.mutable.SetBuilder.$plus$eq(SetBuilder.scala:22)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.SetBuilder.$plus$plus$eq(SetBuilder.scala:22)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.to(TraversableLike.scala:629)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.to(Traversable.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toSet(TraversableOnce.scala:267)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.toSet(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.containsChild$lzycompute(TreeNode.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.containsChild(TreeNode.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:280)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)

[more stack]
```

***Questions:***

1: Why am I getting a StackOverflowError from a relatively small file?

2: Is there a workaround that doesn't require increasing the jvm stack size?

Comment: 1) StackOverflow has no relationship with file size. You will get OutOfMemoryError if file size is an issue 2) It seems the lambda function you are passing to map is recursive (without break condition) which pollutes java stack and creates stack overflow. I would suggest revisit your map function. May be first replace it with simple lambda expression to test then identify the recursive part and add a break condition to the recursive. That should solve this issue.

Comment: I don't think the anonymous function I'm passing to map is the problem, because if I delete the cacheTable call without changing the lambda function passed to map, I no longer receive a StackOverflow exception.

Comment: I am also learner, but if you are saying cacheTable comment resolving the issue, then problem might http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487579/error-in-caching-a-table-in-sparksql  which version of spark you are using

Comment: I'm using Spark 1.6.1, and it appears that the problem in the linked SO question deals with NoSuchTableException, which isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does your SQL has this condition?https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13657 It seems this is opened on 1.6 and resolved for 2.0 Based on stack trace, catalyst.trees.TreeNode.containsChild it seems catalyst SQL is what causing this issue.